# "The pdf.js library could not be found." (PDF module)

Tags: 7, files, theming

I installed pdf.js with the [PDF](http://drupal.org/project/pdf) module in an effort to show pdf on the fly on my Drupal 7 site. I keep Drupal 7 constantly upgraded on Ubuntu on an instance an AWS.

I installed the module using drush which placed the module at `sites/all/modules/pdf`. I then copied pdf.js to: `sites/all/libraries`.

After installing I have created a new content type called PDF and I added a file field that is able to only include a pdf file.

I selected the display to show: "PDF: Default viewer of PDF.js". I then added a content with a PDF file in it selected and uploaded.

While trying to show it I get the message: `The pdf.js library could not be found.` And down the page: `pdf: Please download and install pdf.js`!

Can anyone help?
Where do I put the JS file?
Is there a problem with the FDF module?

Comment: How you installed it? Where this message came from? What modules are supposed to use it?.. You know what you mean and what you did. We don't; we only know what you actually wrote.

Comment: Sorry' you are absolutely right' here is everything:
I installed Drupal 7 (the latest and constantly upgraded on Ubuntu on an instance an AWS.
In an attempt to show PDF file to people that have no PDF client installed I have installed the PDF module From: https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf
I installed the module using drush  which placed the module at sites/all/modules/pdf
I thene copied  pdf.js to: " sites/all/libraries "
After installing I have created a new content type called PDF and I added a file field that is able to only include a pdf file
(I will continue an another comment down)

Comment: I selected the display to show: "PDF: Default viewer of PDF.js"
I then added a content with a PDF file in it selected and uploaded and while trying to show it I get the message: The pdf.js library could not be found.
And down the page: pdf:  Please download and install pdf.js!
Can anyone  help with this?
Thanks
Shimon Dekel

Comment: Please use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/130012/edit) link.

Answer (score 1):

The path will be like this /sites/all/libraries/pdf.js.

pdf.js is a FOLDER not a FILE. It is very strange to have a folder with a DOT in the name.

I have attached a screenshot on the folder hierarchy that works.

SUMMARY:

The folder in your libraries folder must be named: pdf.js, you will have to rename the top folder of anything you download to pdf.js (in this instance pdf.js is not a FILE, but the container of the library)
See screenshot for the correct file hierarchy.

[image: PDF.js libraries folder structure]